# How to fix ion-slides deformed width on ios?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-slides

Sometimes `ion-slides` on iOS are deformed (`ion-slide` have wrong width and is overflowed).

Setting `width: 100% !important` and `overflow: hidden` fix the problem partially but brings up a new bug which is the white space to death screen after the last slide.

Using the `slides.update()` function doesn't fix the problem (ionic 3).

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `ion-slides` were hardcoded in the HTML page.

So, I had packed the slides data into an array in the `ts` file and looped the `ion-slide` tag using `*ngFor` with 1s delay after the `ionViewWillLoad()` had fired.

TS code:

```
 ...
 slides = null;
 ...

 ionViewWillEnter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.slides = [
        {
          imgSrc: "...",
          header: "...",
          text: "...",
          action: "skip"
        },
        {
          imgSrc: "...",
          header: "...",
          text: "...",
          action: "skip"
        },
        {
          imgSrc: "...",
          header: "...",
          text: "...",
          action: "skip"
        }
      ]
    }, 1000);
  }
```

HTML code:

```
  <ion-slides *ngIf="slides" pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
      <img [src]="slide.imgSrc" class="slide-image" />
      <h2 class="text-heading">{{ slide.header }}</h2>
      <p class="text-light" text-capitalize [innerHTML]="slide.text"></p>
      <span (click)="goToMenu()" class="text-light" text-capitalize>{{ slide.action }}</span>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: No need setTimeout is fine